# DropboxUnlinkedException but the session already had token inside and user didn't revoke the access

Tags: authentication, dropbox, access-token, dropbox-api

My problem is I have existing user in database which store the key and secret from the first authentication. I wish to reuse it again when I come back. For the first time authentication, everything working fine. I can use every method call from Dropbox API and the Token(key and secret) was stored in database.

I come back to app and get the Token from database, set it to the session, link current session with API.

```
session = new WebAuthSession(appKeys, ACCESS_TYPE);
api = new DropboxAPI<WebAuthSession>(session);
String userKey = dropboxUserObj.getUserKey(); //Key from database
String userSecret = dropboxUserObj.getUserSecret();//Secret from database
AccessTokenPair userAccessTokenPair = new AccessTokenPair(userKey, userSecret);
session.setAccessTokenPair(userAccessTokenPair);
```

It return DropboxUnlinkedException to me when I want to get user data from api using

```
String userDisplayName = api.accountInfo().displayname;
```

I have checked on debug mode. Api was linked with the current session. The current session stored Appkey and user's token and correct access type. The point that I doubt is I saw "client = null". I maybe forgot something but I check them all, try every possibilities I can think of but it still return me "DropboxUnlinkedException" which mean I haven't set an access token pair on the session and I didn't revoke access for sure.

Please help me figure out...

I added a screenshot maybe it can illustrate my problem
[image]

Comment: did u find a solution?

Comment: Yes, I did. I have save the request token pair instead of access token pair after the first authentication. The right way is save to access token pair. The access token pair can be use for the further login, if it still valid and not revoke by user. For the "client =null" problem, this solved if you set the access token to the WebAuthSession. None of them is null if you do it right way!

Comment: @Takumi Can you please explain your answer little more . Please.

Comment: What do you want me to explain??? Please tell me, I think I explain it clear already(IMO)